# Setting up Ubuntu-Open Suse dual boot

Tags: 10.10, installation, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual boot with Ubuntu 11.04, OpenSUSE 11.4 and/or Fedora 15 beta. Does the order matters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37771/dual-boot-with-ubuntu-11-04-opensuse-11-4-and-or-fedora-15-beta-does-the-order)

I'm running `Ubuntu 10.10`, but I was to also test out the newest versions of `Open Suse`. I want to dual boot between `Ubuntu 10.10` and `Open Suse 11.4`.

Is there a quick solution to set this up, perhaps via the open suse iso installer?

Comment: Wouldn't VirtualBox be more convenient for testing?

Comment: @ATMathew - OpenSuse installation insists on deleting Ubuntu - not very nice.  Its easier to install OpenSuse first and then install Ubuntu to get a dual boot working... Or as Steve-o says - just use virtualbox - easier and faster!